# Internet Explorer material icons in pseudo element not working

Tags: html, css

On my Website I've added an icon before the text "Startseite":

---

[image]

---

But on IE the icon is gone. I don't know why. I think I did everything to make it workable in IE:
[image]

---

This is my code which should add the icon before the element Startseite:

```css
.woocommerce-breadcrumb > a::before {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    margin-right: 6px;
    font-size: 17.5px;
    content: 'home';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
<nav class="woocommerce-breadcrumb"><a>Startseite</a>&nbsp;/&nbsp;Tests</nav>
```

Comment: Not sure which IE version you are talking about, try with a single `:` instead of `::`, it should work in all the browsers.

Comment: I tried it already with a single : but it's still not working. I'm trying it with IE11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known problem when using Material Design icons via `content: 'icon-name';` in IE 11.

To fix it you need to enable font ligatures for the pseudo element:

```
font-feature-settings: 'liga';
```

Check this github issue for reference:

> https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/536#issuecomment-389504628

Comment: Oh never thought in this way. I'll try it now and let you know if it works.